# How to get public profile picture url without user id within url?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I want to show profile pictures of people in my facebook html5 game using graph api. However, my problem is that I don't want, other people using my game, to find out other people's facebook ids by simply right clicking on the picture.

Is there any way to get profile pictures of people from facebook with ambiguous picture url?

Comment: Can we get more information on how people are chosen to be displayed (ie, why are you getting X's picture?)? EDIT: I should clarify why this  is relavent: if they are there more than momentarily, hosting it on your server under a different, unique id of your own may be preferable.

Comment: Yea this is an obvious solution but yet costly!